# Как реализовать многократный вызов AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Есть класс `AsyncTask`, который в методе `doInBackground` загружает из сети значение, а в методе `onPostExecute` вставляет его в TextView. Проблема в том, что TextView несколько, а значения загружаются с разных ссылок. Нужно чтобы при вызове класса `AsyncTask`и по очереди заполнялись все TextView. **Как правильно реализовать поставленную задачу?** Пробовал помещать `AsyncTask` в цикл, но тогда методы `doInBackground` и `onPostExecute` начинают работать асинхронно. Пробовал так же помещать в цикл по отдельности(и вместе) методы `doInBackground` и `onPostExecute`, но всё равно получается путаница.  Постарался как можно понятнее изложить проблему.

p.s.Код специально не стал выкладывать, чтобы еще сильнее не запутать. Если без него не получится разобраться, то выложу.
Если требуется получить значения для одного TextView, то все работает без проблем, но как только появляется несколько TextView, то начинается хаос в методе `doInBackground`

Comment: Как я понял, вас не устраивает то, что если запускать задачи циклом, они выполняются не одновременно?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В doinBackground после полученного результата вызывайте метод publishProgress в котором входящие параметры это значение вашего результата и какому textview передавать это значение.
Далее в AsynkTask переопределить метод onProgressUpdate.
После каждого вызова метода publishProgress будет выполнятся метод onProgressUpdate